# Find out detailed information about X.509 certificate the ERP user logged on with

Tags: certificate, abap, soa, x509, sap-erp

I am developing an SAP Enterprise Service that allows the user to logon via an X.509 certificate. Internally, there is a mapping in the customizing between the external user ID and the internal ERP user name.

In my logic I need to determine whether the user has logged on via basic authentication (user/password, technically still possible) or via the certificate. I think I can manage it by calling a kernel routine (LOGIN_INFO).

However, how do I obtain details about the certificate the user used to logon? I want to check if the certificate was issued by a certain certification authority.

Any experience here?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CL_HTTP_SECURITY_SESSION* classes. In fact, the class CL_HTTP_SECURITY_SESSION_ADMIN has a method that gives us from table SECURITY_CONTEXT the logon method of the session.

```
DATA: lt_sessions TYPE security_context_tab,
      ls_session  LIKE LINE OF lt_sessions.    
lt_sessions = cl_http_security_session_admin=>list_security_session_contexts(  ).
```

There is a field AUTHNMETHODS, which stores the auth method in a numerical format: ie 8000 is basic authentication.

There is a method in the same class: DECOMPOSE_AUTHNMETHODS_FIELD, which should help you to get the auth method.

Hope this helps, i've never implemented this on a Enterprise Service,so i'm not sure this class could be helpful, but on some http straightforward connections to the SICF it works well.

Regards